# Drawing east and west line in the circle?

Tags: android, math, digital-compass

I am currently building a small compass app and I have drawn the north and south line 
using simple circle equation: x= a+r Cos(t) and y= b+ r Sin(t) where t=heading or direction in degree(angle). More info in Wiki

**So far** I have manged to get the north and south line. Here is my work

```
    //canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint)

    //Drawing North
        canvas.drawLine(cxCompass, cyCompass, 
                (float)(cxCompass + radiusCompass * Math.sin((double)(-direction) * 3.14/180)), 
                (float)(cyCompass - radiusCompass * Math.cos((double)(-direction) * 3.14/180)), 
                paint);

    //Drawing South
        canvas.drawLine(cxCompass, cyCompass, 
                (float)(cxCompass - radiusCompass * Math.sin((double)(-direction) * 3.14/180)), 
                (float)(cyCompass + radiusCompass * Math.cos((double)(-direction) * 3.14/180)), 
                paint);
```

**My problem:** I don't know how do we get the east and west line?

CxCompass, CyCompass: coordinates of circle center

Comment: I suggest reading through this... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_haversines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding 90 degrees.
I am happy to share it

```
            //Drawing west
        canvas.drawLine(cxCompass, cyCompass, 
                (float)(cxCompass + radiusCompass * Math.sin((double)(-direction-90) * 3.14/180)), 
                (float)(cyCompass - radiusCompass * Math.cos((double)(-direction-90) * 3.14/180)), 
                paint);

        //Drawing east
        canvas.drawLine(cxCompass, cyCompass, 
                (float)(cxCompass - radiusCompass * Math.sin((double)(-direction-90) * 3.14/180)), 
                (float)(cyCompass + radiusCompass * Math.cos((double)(-direction-90) * 3.14/180)), 
                paint);
```